# toggle mirroring for external displays with scene based app life cycle

Tags: ios, uikit

External screen support changed for iOS 13 when using scene based app life cycle.

Previously it was possible to implement external screen support for some parts of your app and rely on mirroring for other parts.

I cannot figure out how to get similar behaviour on iOS 13 with scene based app life cycle. To support non-mirroring for any screens I need to support opening a scene with the external display role, but once this is shown there is no way deactivate the scene to get mirroring.

It might be possible to implement mirroring manually, but I cannot find any efficient way to mirror one of the other scenes.

Anyone know how to toggle mirroring for external displays or how to implement mirroring manually where everything from the UIWindow of another scene is shown in the UIWindow of the external screen?

Comment: Older documentation states that a UIScreen without a window will perform mirroring so I tried to set the screen property of the window to nil but this just made the external screen black. 


I also asked UIApplication.shares to shut down the session for the external screen but this had no effect.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue. and found the solution here:
IMPORTANCE: in the info.plist, please use external display session role (legacy), do not use non-interaction type!!!

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
        let sceneConfiguration: UISceneConfiguration

        if connectingSceneSession.role == .windowExternalDisplay {
            sceneConfiguration = UISceneConfiguration.init(name: "External Display Configuration", sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)

            // Removing the storyboard prevents the external display scene from being used
            if Settings.shared.externalDisplay == false {
                sceneConfiguration.storyboard = nil
            }
        } else {
            sceneConfiguration = UISceneConfiguration(name: "Default Configuration", sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
        }

        return sceneConfiguration
    }
```

from :https://hacknicity.medium.com/external-display-support-versus-stage-manager-on-ipados-16-149e15dc700e